# Use Linq Any query or Expressions to build query for performance

Tags: c#, mysql, lambda, entity-framework-6, expression

we are Entity Framework in our project. Need to know the performance impact between .ANY() and Expressions to form Where clause.

In the below function i used two approach to get result:

**APPROACH 1 - Form Lambda expression query using ANY()**
From my observation using .Any() is not adding where clause when query is executed(checked in sql profiler) what EF does is gets all matched inner joined records store in-memory and then apply condition specified in .ANY()

**APPROACH 2 - Form Expression Query Starts**
With Expressions i'm explicitly forming where clause and executing.checked the same in SQL query Profiler i'm able to see where clause. 
Note: To form expression where clause i'm doing additional loops and "CombinePredicates".

Now, my doubts are:

1. which approach will improve performance. Do i need to go with Lambda
   with .ANY() or Expressions?
2. what is the right way to from where clause to improve performance?

If not the two approach suggest me the right way to do it

```
private bool GetClientNotifications(int clientId, IList<ClientNotification> clientNotifications)
{
IList<string> clientNotificationList = null;
var clientNotificationsExists = clientNotifications?.Select(x => new { x.Name, x.notificationId 
}).ToList();
if (clientNotificationsExists?.Count > 0)
{

    //**Approach 1 => Form Lamada  Query starts**
    notificationList = this._clientNotificationRepository?.FindBy(x => clientNotificationsExists.Any(x1 => x.notificationId == x1.notificationId && x.clientId == 
  clientId)).Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
    **//Form Lamada  Query Ends**

    //**Approach 2 =>Form Expression Query Starts**
    var filterExpressions = new List<Expression<Func<DbModel.ClientNotification, bool>>>();
    Expression<Func<DbModel.ClientNotification, bool>> predicate = null;
    foreach (var clientNotification in clientNotificationsExists)
    {
        predicate = a => a.clientId == clientId && a.notificationId == clientNotification .notificationId;
        filterExpressions.Add(predicate);
    }
    predicate = filterExpressions.CombinePredicates<DbModel.ClientNotification>(Expression.OrElse);
    clientNotificationList = this._clientNotificationRepository?.FindBy(predicate).Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
    //**Form Expression Query Ends**
}
return clientNotificationList;
  }
```

If non of the approaches were good please suggest me the right way to do.

Comment: Also compare the raw sql it generates. also check your db is indexed correctly in any case, which will be the largest bottle neck

Comment: db tables are indexed properly. here i need to know the best approach to improve performance from the mentioned scenarios

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the clientId being used on both approaches is used on conditions linked to clientNotificationsExists but there is no actual relationship with its objects so this condition can be moved up one level. This might bring a minuscule benefit as the overall sql will be smaller without the duplicate clauses.

From the described behavior the first approach filter is not being translated to sql so it is being resolved at the client side however, if it could be translated the performance would be similar or identical.

If you want to generate an IN sql clause you can use an array and use the Contains method within your filter expression. That could perhaps improve a little bit but don't get your hopes too high.

Try the following:

```
private bool GetClientNotifications(int clientId, IList<ClientNotification> clientNotifications)
{
    IList<string> clientNotificationList = null;
    var clientNotificationsExists = clientNotifications?
        .Select(x => new { x.Name, x.notificationId }).ToList();
    if (clientNotificationsExists?.Count > 0)
    {
        var notificationIds = clientNotificationsExists.Select(x => x.notificationId).ToArray();
        clientNotificationList = this._clientNotificationRepository?
            .FindBy(x => x.clientId == clientId && notificationIds.Contains(x.notificationId));
    }
    return clientNotificationList;
}
```